# Нужно что бы при нажатии на каждую кнопку менялся текст только для этой кнопки

Tags: javascript, html5

> есть 3 <div> (у всех class="box")  в каждом из этих блоков есть <p> (class="box__text)  и <button> (class="box_btn") у всех div, p и button одинаковые классы, нужно чтобы при нажатии на каждую кнопку менялся текст только для этой кнопки, id трогать нельзя. Что я делаю не так?

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.box_btn');

btns.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
    el.target.closest('.box').classList.toggle('.box_text2');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box_text {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.box_btn {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 110px;
}

.box_text2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p class="box_text"> Lorem, ipsum dolor.
  </p>
  <button class="box_btn">Button</button>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p class="box_text"> Lorem, ipsum dolor.
  </p>
  <button class="box_btn">Button</button>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p class="box_text"> Lorem, ipsum dolor.
  </p>
  <button class="box_btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: А в какой строчке кода JS вы ожидаете, что произойдёт изменение текста?

Comment: Все что Вы делаете, это добавляете класс на клик и то, там должно быть указание имени класса без точки `toggle('box_text2')`, а так у Вас даже тогл класса на клик не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Такс пройдёмся по коду:

- В метод `toggle` класс надо передавать без точки, но и это не поможет вам
- `closest` возвращает родительский элемент, ему вы ставите новый класс `box_text2`. Несмотря на то что вы там указали цвет красный - это не значит, что это свойство CSS перепишет цвет для всех дочерних элементов. Это сработало бы, если вы указали `inherit` для цвета текста кнопки. Но т.к. вы его не указали, то переписать не получится, даже если напишите `!important`

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.box_btn');

btns.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
    el.target.closest('.box').classList.toggle('box_text2');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box_text {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.box_btn {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 110px;
  color: inherit;
}

.box_text2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p class="box_text"> Lorem, ipsum dolor.
  </p>
  <button class="box_btn">Button</button>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p class="box_text"> Lorem, ipsum dolor.
  </p>
  <button class="box_btn">Button</button>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p class="box_text"> Lorem, ipsum dolor.
  </p>
  <button class="box_btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Как я понимаю вам нужно менять цвет текста по клику.

Во первых: в методе toggle вам нужно указать не селектор, а именно название класса то есть вместо `toggle('.box_text2')` нужно написать `toggle('box_text2')`

Во вторых: callback функция в методе addEventListener первым параметром получает не сам элемент, а вызванное событие. (то что вы написали el вместо event как я, на данный код не повлияет, но может сбить вас с толку в будущем).

В третьих: вы добавляете/удаляете класс `box_text2` у `div` элемента, а нужно у элемента `p` поэтому через этот `div` можно найти лежащий в нём `p` элемент.

Совет: почаще смотрите код через панель разработчика. В хроме нажимаете в любом месте правой кнопкой мыши и жмёте "Посмотреть код"

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.box_btn');

btns.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const box =  event.target.closest('.box')
    const boxText = box.querySelector('.box_text')
    boxText.classList.toggle('box_text2');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box_text {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.box_btn {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 110px;
}

.box_text2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p class="box_text"> Lorem, ipsum dolor.
  </p>
  <button class="box_btn">Button</button>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p class="box_text"> Lorem, ipsum dolor.
  </p>
  <button class="box_btn">Button</button>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p class="box_text"> Lorem, ipsum dolor.
  </p>
  <button class="box_btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Лучше было вешать один обработчик на всплытие.

Comment: Вы меняете цвет текста параграфа, а надо кнопки

Comment: Прошу не судить строго, так как только начал вникать в это...

Comment: @EzioMercer, зачем тогда над каждой кнопкой некий текст?

Comment: @HTOHOT А какая разница что над каждой кнопкой? Задача в смене цвета текста кнопки и всё

Comment: @EzioMercer, но по классам же понятно, какой именно текст он хотел менять

Comment: @HTOHOT Ой, поверьте мне это далеко не самые странные требования, которые мне удалось повидать на этом сайте. Потому я обычно отвечаю чётко по задаче. Если хотите предложить что-то своё, то можете дополнить вопрос чем-то типа "А если вам нужно было ...", но в большинстве случаев авторам будет плевать на ваши рекомендации, возьмут решение и уйдут. Но рекомендации как по мне очень полезны будущим "искателям приключений", потому я их иногда даю, но это лично моё мнение

Comment: @EzioMercer на рекомендации мне не будет плевать) 
я только начал учиться и взялся за сложную задачу, возможно не особо четко передал суть задачи за это извиняюсь, смысл был изменить текст, неважно цвет это будет или параграф. За решение большое спасибо, но сейчас я понял что нужно сидеть и понимать event.Target & currentTarget, а так же разбираться с childNode и children.

Comment: @ВиталийЧистяков Я лично в ваш адрес и не говорил) Вы просили цвет кнопки, я сделал смену цвета кнопки,  HTOHOT-же, предположил, что вы скорее всего хотите смену цвета параграфа, потому пошёл другим путём. Это мы и обсуждали) А вы примите пожалуйста один из ответов, если он вам помог